# Getting app name that broadcast a intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-gps

I'm developing an app that tracks the usage of the GPS (not only if the GPS was turned on/off but the location requests).

After a research I find out that I can archive this by using the following code in my manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".triggers.TriggerGPS">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is working, every time that an app request the GPS coordinates my TriggerGPS class is invoked.

```
public class TriggerGPS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String currentDatetime = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" +
                    c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +
                    c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

            Log.d("---------log--------", "Intent ( " + intent.getAction() + " ) GPS Status onReceive : " + currentDatetime);
    }
}
```

But my app should create a report indicating each app is using the GPS and how many times the app used the GPS to get de coordinates per day.

The problem here is that I can't figure out how to get the app name that broadcast the event.

There's any way to do that?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here is that I can't figure out how to get the app name that broadcast the event.

Apps do not broadcast that `Intent`. The system broadcasts that `Intent`. You have no way of determining why the user changed their device settings to enable or disable a location provider. After all, there does not have to be a specific app-driven reason. The user could simply elect to tap on the tile in the notification shade, go into Settings and toggle the provider state, or otherwise change the state just for giggles.

Comment: But this receive "android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE" does not track the change state of the GPS between on/off. It's tracking the request for the GPS coordinates.

Comment: But I understand what you said. Thank you for you help! :D

Comment: I understood. A another that I found to know that the GPS was used by an app (any app) was using the PASSIVE_PROVIDER. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER